# What is the b'racha for tortillas?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food

Is a Tortillah considered lechem (bread), pas habab'knisin (cake/cracker/pie which assumes the status of bread AIUI when one "makes it a seudah"), or is it a stam mezunos? I haven't seen it explicitly mentioned on the various b'rachos lists.

Comment: related (slightly): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15210/figuring-out-a-kzayit-by-weight-volume-of-ingredients

Comment: Does it matter that lafa and pita are baked whilst tortillas are fried?

Comment: @flatbread tortillas are not fried. They are baked on a dry heated surface.

Answer (score 7):

Are you asking about **wheat** or **corn** flour tortillahs?

**Wheat** flour tortillas are essentially a flat bread, a bit thinner than pitas. ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flour_tortilla ) . I see no reason that their *bracha* should be anything other than *HaMotzi* as they do not fit into any of the definitions of *Pas HaBa'ah B'Kisanin*.

**Corn** flour tortillas are made with corn meal ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corn_tortilla ) and like anything made with corn meal (such as corn chips or tortilla chips) their *bracha* is *Shehakol*.

I do not have written sources for you on these exact items, but based on basic *Hilchos Berachos"* these are the correct *berachos* for these two items.

Comment: I guess I was thinking more of flour tortillas, but  corn tortillas often contain wheat flour as well which it seems to me would complicate things.

There is a makloches, as I understand it, between Ashkenazi poskim and Sefardic poskim about the status of matzah (excluding Pesach) so it strikes me at least as plausible that this would effect the status of wheat tortillas ( perhaps even for Ashkenazim?) Just speculating.

Comment: (Modern day) Matzah is a brittle cracker and for the majority of the year is considered by the Sefaradim to be Pas HaBaah Bikisanin. Wheat tortillas are soft and foldable and are no different than a Lafah or Pita. Someone may disagree and I would love to hear why.

Comment: And if it is a corn tortilla made with wheat flour, one must determine the purpose of the wheat flour to decide what bracha to make.

Comment: My Sephardi rabbi suggested to me that soft matzah (like you can get from http://www.softmatza.com/) might be Hamotzi year round.

Comment: Might be? If I'm not mistaken the discussion of mezonos on matzah is only discussed regarding hard matzos.

Answer (score 3):

Concerning corn tortillas, it is also possible for the brachah to be ha-adamah. If the nixtamalized corn is directly made to tortilla rather than processed to flour, the corn kernels would still be recognizable.

As noted on the OU site:

"Say borei pri ha’eitz or borei pri ha’adama for foods made of identifiable pieces of fruit or vegetables.

Note: Even if you know the ingredients in a prepared food–such as grated apples–you must see identifiable pieces in order to say a specific blessing (borei pri ha’eitz, borei pri ha’adama…). If no ingredients are visually identifiable, you must say she’hakol (or possibly borei minei mezonot)." [OU.org](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/halacha-lmaaseh/types-of-blessings/)

See also Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 52:16
And (if I am correct) Seder Birkat Hanehenin 7:23 by the Ba'al HaTanya

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Menachem! Consider editing in sources regarding the halakhot you reference.

Comment: @mevaqesh I can't find where I noted it, but found another source.

Comment: Excellent. You could further improve it, with a link to the OU website.

Comment: I also added two more sources

Comment: +1 Very good. Consider also clarifying what the Kitzur and the other sefer say.