# What blessing is made on a taco, burrito, or plain flour tortilla?

Tags: blessing, food, bread, mezonot-beracha, hamotzi-beracha

My copy of "Guide to Blessings, The Brochos for Various Foods" compiled by Rabbi Naftali Hoffner (NCSY/OU) states that tortillas get the "Shehakol" blessing because they are made of maize (corn) flour.  This would make sense for corn tortillas ("hard shell tacos"), but I am not certain about flour tortillas ("soft shell tacos").  They are usually made from wheat flour without any corn.

Obviously, one *could* make a Shehakol on them (based on the famous advice "when in doubt, go for a Shehakol"), but my question is: Are they a flat-bread so that one should say "Hamotzi" or they a general wheat product so that "Mezonot" is more appropriate?

Comment: Soft tortillas come in both wheat and corn, FYI.

Comment: dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/tortilla-in-halachah?

Comment: The Bracha Achrona question is a much bigger deal, as bentching after bread is deorayta.

Answer (score 2):

In a personal conversation, Rav Shmuel Kaminetzky said that they do not have "tzuras hapas" (the form of bread) and are therefore mezonos.

Rabbi Bodner once showed R' Elyashiv a tortilla and he said that it *did* have tzuras hapas.  (There are other factors that could nonetheless make it not Hamotzi, but R' Bodner did not ask about them).

I was actually just speaking to someone who told me that when Rabbi Fuerst of Chicago came to the Cincinnati Kollel, he assumed as obvious (after saying that it was a justified question) that a wrap has tzuras hapas.

Comment: Video of Rav Elyashiv ruling on tortilla https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tpuWjf5oiZs saying that it does NOT have a "torisah de'nahama" [tzuras hapas].

Answer (score 1):

[Video of Rav Dovid Feinstein ruling that wraps made from wheat flour are considered "bread", and their bracha is "hamotzi".](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Osqbd7tHHw)