# May fried dough be used for Lechem Mishneh?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, food, challah-shabbat-bread, orach-chaim

May fried dough be used for the Lechem Mishneh (double loaves of bread) of Shabbat? Or is there any requirement for it being baked? If being baked is not an inherent requirement, is it still preferred Lechatlicha to eat with  regardless? Please provide a source for this question amongst Poskim.

Comment: There are dozens of rules specific to the category of bread. Do you have some reason to think Lechem Mishne is unique here that you ask about it in particular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lechem Mishna is actually a d'rabannan, higher than a mere minhag. Breads cooked with liquids other than water are not suitable for use as bread unless you have nothing else to use.

Fried dough would not be suitable. A regular loaf that has been fried is better but its status as bread is disputed.

[https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1108296/jewish/Lechem-Mishneh-The-Two-Shabbat-Loaves.htm#:~:text=The%20Torah%20Source,-When%20the%20Israelites&text=3%20To%20commemorate%20this%20miracle,are%20known%20as%20Lechem%20Mishneh](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1108296/jewish/Lechem-Mishneh-The-Two-Shabbat-Loaves.htm#:%7E:text=The%20Torah%20Source,-When%20the%20Israelites&text=3%20To%20commemorate%20this%20miracle,are%20known%20as%20Lechem%20Mishneh).

[Do you make bircat Hamotzi on fried bread?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/41229/do-you-make-bircat-hamotzi-on-fried-bread)